# Is it justified to use Stored Procedure instead of View just because I want to include variables in code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a Select statement, and for readability and clarity reasons I am using variables/table variables inside - in this particular context it makes to code much easier to understand.

Since I am using variables I can not store this select as `VIEW`, and I am wondering if making it a `Stored Procedure` is a right way to go.

I am aware that I could build view differently, using table-valued functions etc, but it is essential for me that the entire "solution" is contained in one SQL object (ease of deployment between environments, trackability).

Is `Stored Procedure` right way to go then? Or should it not be used as a replacement for views?

CODE:

```sql
-- Supporting tables

DECLARE @Years TABLE (Year INT)
DECLARE @RevenueInTime TABLE (
    [RequestID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Duration] [bigint] NULL,
    [OneTime] [bigint] NULL,
    [Monthly] [bigint] NULL,
    [year] [bigint] NULL,
    [m1] [bigint] NULL,
    [m2] [bigint] NULL,
    [m3] [bigint] NULL,
    [m4] [bigint] NULL,
    [m5] [bigint] NULL,
    [m6] [bigint] NULL,
    [m7] [bigint] NULL,
    [m8] [bigint] NULL,
    [m9] [bigint] NULL,
    [m10] [bigint] NULL,
    [m11] [bigint] NULL,
    [m12] [bigint] NULL
)
DECLARE @Revenue TABLE(
    [RequestID] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [DurationInMonths] [bigint] NULL,
    [Rev_OneTime] [bigint] NULL,
    [Rev_Monthly] [int] NULL
)

DECLARE @CurrYear INT 
DECLARE @MinYear INT
DECLARE @MaxYear INT
;

/* 
Create Table holding esseintal information about each Request (record per Request) 
ID, StartDate, Duration, One-Time Revenue, Monthly Revenue
*/
WITH OneTime AS (
SELECT
    RequestId,
    ROUND(SUM(Revenue), 0)  AS Rev_OneTime
FROM costs
WHERE NonRecurring = 'Y'
GROUP BY RequestId
),
Reccuring_one AS (
SELECT
    RequestId,
    SUM(Revenue) AS Rev_Reccuring,
    MAX(DurationInMonths) AS Duration
FROM costs
WHERE NonRecurring = 'N'
GROUP BY RequestId
),
Recurring AS (
SELECT
    RequestId,
    CASE 
        WHEN Duration = 0 THEN 0 
        ELSE ROUND(Rev_Reccuring / Duration, 0 ) 
    END AS Rev_Monthly
FROM Reccuring_one
),
DistRequests AS (
SELECT
    DISTINCT RequestID, StartDate, DurationInMonths

FROM costs
), Revenue AS (
SELECT 
    DR.RequestID,
    DR.StartDate,
    DR.DurationInMonths,
    ISNULL(CAST(OT.Rev_OneTime AS bigint), 0) AS Rev_OneTime,
    ISNULL(CAST(R.Rev_Monthly AS INT), 0 ) AS Rev_Monthly

FROM DistRequests DR
LEFT JOIN OneTime OT ON DR.RequestId = OT.RequestId 
LEFT JOIN Recurring R ON DR.RequestId = R.RequestId
)

INSERT INTO @Revenue SELECT * FROM Revenue



-- Calculate Timeframe that should be in scope, i.e year of minimum start date - untill year of maxiumm end date

SET @MinYear = (SELECT MIN(YEAR(StartDate)) FROM @Revenue)
SET @MaxYear = (SELECT MAX(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths,StartDate))) FROM @Revenue)

SET @CurrYear = @MinYear

-- Table populated with each consecutive year for examined period
WHILE @CurrYear <= @MaxYear
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Years VALUES (@CurrYear)
    SET @CurrYear = @CurrYear + 1
END 

SET @CurrYear = @MinYear
;



-- Loop through each year, and create record for each requests that is ongoing during it
DECLARE year_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT  Year FROM @Years

OPEN year_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM  year_cursor INTO @CurrYear

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO @RevenueInTime
    (
        [RequestID]
    ,[StartDate]
    ,[Duration]
    ,[OneTime]
    ,[Monthly]
    ,[year]
    ,[m1]
    ,[m2]
    ,[m3]
    ,[m4]
    ,[m5]
    ,[m6]
    ,[m7]
    ,[m8]
    ,[m9]
    ,[m10]
    ,[m11]
    ,[m12]
    )


    SELECT 
        RequestID,
        StartDate,
        DurationInMonths,
        Rev_OneTime,
        Rev_Monthly,
        @CurrYear AS year, 
        --If inspected month is between StartDate and End Date of project set RevenueMonthly, else set 0
        --Use EOMONTH to make sure that all Requests regardless of DAY of StartDate qualify
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 1, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 2, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 3, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 4, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 5, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 6, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 7, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 8, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 9, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 10, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 11, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end,
        CASE WHEN EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(@CurrYear, 12, 1)) BETWEEN StartDate AND DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths ,StartDate) then Rev_Monthly else 0 end   

    FROM @Revenue

    WHERE YEAR(StartDate) <= @CurrYear  AND    YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,DurationInMonths,StartDate))   >= @CurrYear

    FETCH NEXT FROM year_cursor INTO @CurrYear 
END 

CLOSE year_cursor  
DEALLOCATE year_cursor 

SELECT 
RIT.* 
FROM @RevenueInTime RIT
```

Comment: That wouldn't be able to be a `VIEW` anyway, it has a `WHILE `and `CURSOR` in it. The fact that you do have both of those, however, smells like you have a (major) design flaw.

Comment: The obvious replacement for a view is a table valued function, you can select from it just the same as a view, but pass in parameters.

Comment: Even without the cursor and the loop, you still have insert statements. This can't be a view.
BTW, this SQL is neither clear nor readable.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - any hints on how to improve it?

Comment: Change the multiple `case` expressions to a look up table, change the cursor to a set based operation, and try not to do too many things in one procedure. If you have  a procedure containing multiple steps, use `BEGIN...END` and comments to divide it to parts.